# c function returns but python ctypes crashes

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I made compiled some c functions into a dll. The following function is an example:

```
typedef struct {
    faces_array* faces_arr;
    vert_array* verts_arr;
    size_t added; 
    location3d max_values; 
    location3d min_values; 
}mesh;

void init_mesh(mesh* m, const size_t added, const size_t initial_size){ //initial_size is added by mistake, will be deleted
    printf("entered function sucessfully \n");
    faces_array* faces_arr;
    printf("face array \n");
    faces_arr-> faces = malloc(added * sizeof(triFace));
    printf("memory allocated \n");
    faces_arr->capacity_faces = added;
    printf("capacity changed \n");
    faces_arr->num_faces = 0;

    vert_array* verts_arr;
    verts_arr->verts = malloc(added*sizeof(vertex));
    verts_arr->capacity_verts = added;
    verts_arr->num_verts = 0;

    m->added = added;
    m->faces_arr = faces_arr;
    m->verts_arr = verts_arr;
    printf("exited function sucessfully \n");
}
```

I call this function from python using ctypes with:

```
from ctypes import *
class mesh(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
    ('faces_arr', POINTER(faces_array)),
    ('verts_arr', POINTER(vert_array)),
    ('added', c_size_t ),
    ('max_values', location3d ),
    ('min_values', location3d )]
libc = CDLL('./meshing.dll')
init_mesh = lib.__getattr__('init_mesh')
init_mesh.restype = None
init_mesh.argtypes = [POINTER(mesh), c_size_t, c_size_t]
m = mesh()
init_mesh(byref(m), c_size_t(100), c_size_t(100))
```

when I run the python script I see `exited function sucessfully` printed by the c function at the end, indicating that the function worked without problems, but python doesn't continue to work, I can't figure out why this happens. (note: I didn't put all the structures in the code here to not make the question so large.)

Comment: if you print after `init_mesh` in Python do you see it? Can it be, that python crashes when m is being deallocated?

Comment: I tried printing after `init_mesh` and I didn't see it.

Comment: Can the problem be because python can no longer access the `faces_arr` defined inside the function after the return? I'll try changing `m->faces_arr` directly.

Comment: Remove `max_values`, `min_values` and so on from your data structure until you see the one member which is causing problems, i.e make your example truly minimal ([mcve])

Comment: How do you build your *.dll*? Is it *64bit* or *32bit*? Hmm, *faces\_arr* seems to be a dangling pointer. `faces_array *faces_arr = malloc(sizeof(faces_array))`? Also try creating a small *C* *app* that calls the function and see how that works.

Comment: The problem is fixed now by editing the `mesh` pointer directly, I changed every `face_arr->some_attr` into `m->face_arr->some_attr`. thank you!

Comment: So it should have been like this: `faces_array *faces_arr = m->faces_arr;`. Makes sense :) .